# How does Steam prompt me to delete game data when I delete the app?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I recently tried delete Steam.app from Mac OS X 10.10.5. As soon as I hit <kbd>Command-Backspace</kbd> to remove the application, this dialog appeared:

[image]

The text reads:

> Steam still has some game content stored at /Users/apaidnerd/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps.  Do you want to delete the game content as well?
>
> [Leave files] [Reveal in Finder] [Delete files]

How did the Steam application cause this to happen? If I'm developing an app for Mac OS X, where is this documented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close. It looks to me like the launch agent "com.valvesoftware.steamclean" is responsible for this. Unloading the "com.valvesoftware.steam.ipctool" agent/service may effectively disable the other one.

The `steamclean` agent's description plist file is in ~/Library/LaunchAgents.  It doesn't poll. It has a `WatchPaths` key, which asks `launchd` to run it when that path changes. `launchd` uses file system notification techniques to monitor that, which also don't rely on polling.

When that happens, the agent runs the program ~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/steamclean, which is not in the Steam.app bundle. It couldn't be, because the app bundle has been moved or renamed, so `launchd` would not be able to find the program for the agent. `steamclean` is what shows the dialog. You can confirm this by reproducing the dialog and leaving it open. Then, use Activity Monitor to list the processes and filter for "steam".

Comment: Much more detail than my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. Steam has a [launchctl agent](http://launchd.info/) that runs (`com.valvesoftware.steam.ipctool`) out of the `/Applications/Steam.app/` directory. If I stop the daemon and remove the Steam.app, no dialog appears.

It must poll to see if its executable path still exists and prompts the user if goes missing. Also, the inactive-looking title bar implies that this dialog is indeed coming from some sort of background process.